# Number of threads waiting on a condition variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11, synchronization, condition-variable, thread-synchronization

I like to know that is there a way to know the number of threads waiting on a condition variable from the condition variable itself, without using some "count" variable?

Answer (score 1):

No, because in general the number of waiting threads is not reliable even without notifications occurring: right after you retrieve this number a new thread can start waiting or a thread waiting with timeout can stop waiting.